# CSS :focus to permanently alter a sibling

Tags: css

I have the following working but want the change to stick also when the field is no longer in focus.
I there any way of doing that within CSS?

```
.contact-field:focus ~ .label {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -26px, 0px) scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); 
    transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 0.7; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: .contact-field:not(:focus) ~ .label

Comment: @Satif no, because the rule will be fired at the begining

Comment: then I don't fully understand your question

Comment: what would the real world usecase for something like this be? You can only do this with Javascript but I would highly discourage you from doing this because then the user has no info on what he focused and what not.

Comment: Could you post the HTML to your CSS? This would allow us to better understand your problem. I would generally say this is not solvable with CSS but things like this can often be solved using some kind of "trick" or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is intended for styling the page, not to change state. There are hacks that could do what you want to do, but in the end they will all fail one way or another depending on the browser environment.

It's much clearer (and more robust) to use JS for this:

```
document.querySelector('.contact-field').addEventListener('focus', () => {
  document.querySelector('.contact-label').classList.add('visited')
});
```

Comment: I don't know of any single hack that could do what OP wants to do, can you elaborate on this? For performance reasons it would be great if the event listener would be removed after adding the class since it's then not needed any more.

Comment: @cloned you could set a loong `transition-delay` for example :-) As in `input { transition-delay: 100000s;} input:focus {transition-delay: 0s; transform: ...}`

Answer (score 0):

I got a friend to help me out.
This did the trick:

```
$('.contact-field').on('focus', function(){
$(this).addClass('visited');
})
```

And then the CSS:

```
.contact-field:focus ~ .label-in-footer,
.contact-field.visited  ~ .label-in-footer {
transform: translate3d(0px, -26px, 0px) scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); 
transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 0.7; 
}
```